# How does Fabric cli get ip of peer/orderer in the example of byfn?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Could any body tell me how the cli knows the IPs of other peers and orders just according to the Host in the configtx.yaml?
When does the DNS information generated? 
Can anybody also tell me some more information about the configuration below "CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock"?

Answer (score 4):

When you run fabric example, it always refer default credentials or already confirugred fabric configuration.

For example, if you use basic fabric example, you will run [your directory]/fabric-dev-servers/startFabric.sh

this file refer already configured information. One of them is connection profile. If you look at createPeerAdmin.sh file, you can find DevServer_connection.json. This file contains connection information for the fabric network.

As you are using byfn.sh, you can add the host ip address using "extra_hosts" in docker-compose.yaml file.

As there is no definition about this, it will use localhost as default.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4

like this,

```
extra_hosts:
          - "peer0.org1.example.com:192.168.1.10" 
          - "ca.org1.example.com:192.168.1.15"   
          - "peer0.org2.example.com:192.168.1.20"
          - "ca.org2.example.com:192.168.1.25"
```

Comment: I am not able to find startFabric.sh nor DevServer_connection.json in the whole Hyperledger https://github.com/hyperledger. And I don't know which Fabric example you are talking about neither. Would you please share more information? Especially the information about the byfn sample would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can set it using docker-compose.yaml file. Let me change it on my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! Besides setting extra_hosts, are there any Fabric's own settings(non-docker-related) to set the peer ip directly?

Comment: @Moon I didn't try yet, but if you change /etc/hosts you can set the IP address of each node. If you are satisfied with my answer, could you choose my one as a correct answer? It would be helpful for me.

Comment: I had already tried to vote your answer yesterday but I failed due to the system's rule... really sorry, I believe you will get more votes later :)

Comment: @Moon Thank you ;-)